# Repeat 4 same tests in Python

Tags: python, testing

I need to repeat:

```
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(EAStest)
suite = unittest.TestSuite()

# suite.addTest(EAStest("ArmDisarmPin"))
# suite.addTest(EAStest("ArmDisarmPin"))
# suite.addTest(EAStest("ArmDisarmPin"))
# suite.addTest(EAStest("ArmDisarmPin"))
```

I just want to optimize my cde, so it will look nicer.
Thanks

Comment: Use a for loop with range?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(EAStest)
suite = unittest.TestSuite()

for i in range(0,4):
    suite.addTest(EAStest("ArmDisarmPin"))
```